# c# property won't work?

Tags: c#

hello guys i have a form... and i set my properties if the user will click the submit button and after then i will call my add_data function which contains my database query...but the problem is the properties I've set in my form will become empty in my add_data function...why this is happening?

actually i already try adding a messagebox in my form which contains the data in my properties  after setting my properties value and it works fine but when i add it to my databasecon class the messagebox shows null... i try also putting my properties and database query function in the same class and it's working but what i want is to separate my properties and my database query functions...

this is the codes in my properties

```
class persons
{
    //person attributes
    private string fname;
    private string lname;
    private string age;
    private string gnder;
    private string address;
    //initialize
    public persons()
    {
        this.fname = "";
        this.lname = "";
        this.age = "";
        this.gnder = "";
        this.address = "";
    }
    //set and get properties
    public string p_fname
    {
        get { return this.fname; }
        set { this.fname = value; }
    }
    public string p_lname
    {
        get { return this.lname; }
        set { this.lname = value; }
    }
    public string p_age
    {
        get { return this.age; }
        set { this.age = value; }
    }
    public string p_gender
    {
        get { return this.gnder; }
        set { this.gnder = value; }
    }
    public string p_address
    {
        get { return this.address; }
        set { this.address = value; }
    }
}
```

this is the codes in my form

```
public partial class add : Form
{
    persons p = new persons();
    databasecon d = new databasecon();
    private void addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p.p_fname = this.fname.Text;
        p.p_lname = this.lname.Text;
        p.p_age = this.age.Text;
        p.p_gender = this.gender.Text;
        p.p_address = this.address.Text;
        d.add_data();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

and this is the codes in my database connection and queries

```
class databasecon
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
    persons p = new persons();
    public databasecon()
    {
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=../dbsample.mdb";
    }

    public void add_data()
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO person(u_fname,u_lname,u_age,u_gender,u_address)VALUES('" + p.p_fname + "','" + p.p_lname + "','" + p.p_age + "','" + p.p_gender + "','" + p.p_address + "')";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("u_fname", p.p_fname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("u_lname", p.p_lname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("u_age", p.p_age);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("u_gender", p.p_gender);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("u_address", p.p_address);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + e);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("New person has been successfully added.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Too much code. Please reduce it to the smallest amount that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: And "doesn't work" is a poor description of the problem. _What_ doesn't work? What do you expect to happen that doesn't?

Comment: I hope you're just starting out learning C# because almost none of it conforms to C# naming conventions.

Comment: in your add_data, you don't have to add the parameters. only if you're using '?' in your query it's relevant

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass `p` as a parameter to the `add_data` method.

```
public void add_data(persons person)
```

then call it with the parameter:

```
d.add_data(p);
```

and use the properties of `person` in the method:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("u_fname", person.p_fname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("u_lname", person.p_lname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("u_age", person.p_age);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("u_gender", person.p_gender);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("u_address", person.p_address);
```

Comment: thanks men... it works now...i though it's ok because in vb.net it's fine...actually I'm new in c# but i think this is much better than vb.net...thanks men!

Answer (score 1):

you create databasecon() in form and then call add_data method and you don't pass 'persons' instance. in databasecon you use persons istnace which is field in this class. you soudl add parameter do add_data method and pass instance or 'persons' you want to save and use it in command

Answer (score 1):

Your `p` fields in your `add` and `databasecon` classes are separate. When you call `d.add_data()`, the `d` object can only see its instance of `persons p ...`.

To fix this, pass the `persons` object into the add_data method.

```
class databasecon{
    // Remove this line, we pass it into the function below
    /* persons p = new persons(); */

    public void add_data(persons p){
        try{
            // same code as before
        }catch(Exception e){
            // same code
        }
        finally{
            // same
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an instance of Person class which you fill and then use an instance of databasecon which is completely not conntected to the person class you filled. 
Change add_data() to

```
public void add_data(person p) { ... }
```

this will use the properties from p passed as parameter.

You call it like this

```
d.add_data(p);
```

Except for that have a look at some C# for begginers book.

Answer (score 1):

Overlooking the fact that your code is extremely poorly written.

You are not passing in the `persons` class that you created.

Something like

```
public void add_data(persons p) {//..blah}
```

Then

```
private void addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)      {          
    p.p_fname = this.fname.Text;
    p.p_lname = this.lname.Text;          
    p.p_age = this.age.Text;          
    p.p_gender = this.gender.Text;          
    p.p_address = this.address.Text;          
    d.add_data(p);         
    this.Close();      
 }
```

Comment: Beat my by 5 seconds!  Inconcievable!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in the code above, you call `add_data` from your `databasecon` class, which has an instance `p` of Person. Since you are not passing a Person object to your `add_data` method, the empty, unset `p` object is what is being saved to the database.

Adding a Person parameter to add_data and use that when saving the data to the database.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things I don't like in your code.

Let's start however with your specific problem:

Your code contains also a source of security issues and malignous SQL code injection.

You are saving always an empty person and there is a problem with your SQL connection string.

Try this code instead.

```
private void addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        persons p = new persons(); // we use a new instance of person class
        p.p_fname = this.fname.Text;
        p.p_lname = this.lname.Text;
        p.p_age = this.age.Text;
        p.p_gender = this.gender.Text;
        p.p_address = this.address.Text;
        d.add_data(p); // we save the instance of persons
        this.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error : " + e);
    }
}

...

class databasecon
{

    public void add_data(person p) // we need a person as parameter
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=../dbsample.mdb";
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            // this is the correct sql command string
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO person(u_fname,u_lname,u_age,u_gender,u_address) " +
                VALUES (@u_fname, @u_lname, @u_age, @u_gender, @u_address)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("u_fname", p.p_fname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("u_lname", p.p_lname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("u_age", p.p_age);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("u_gender", p.p_gender);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("u_address", p.p_address);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Now let's talk about code style.

Is a good thing to use CamelCase style in your code, look on the web about C# CamelCase:
 Classes and properties should all start with a capitalized letter.

Your class express a single person not a list of persons so its name should be `public class Person`.

Avoid the use achronims or of short names when you can...
p_lname should be LastName, people will thanks you if you make your code more readable, C# is not C and C# is not PHP!

A field or a property with a longer name will not consume more memory than a property with a short and unreadable name :)

Use always strong typing... age is not a string, age is an integer.
The property should be `public int Age`, not a string!

Never use MessageBox in your non-visual classes.
Try to catch for exceptions in your client code, not in your library code!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I 100% understand the issue about I guess it's because your inserting an empty `persons` class into the db.

Your `add_data method should take a person object like so.

```
public void add_data(persons obj)
{
    p = obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

you must pass person object to add_data method

```
public void add_data(persons p)
{
   ...
}
```

and call it:

```
d.add_data(p);
```